Not Able to use MaterialDesignThemes -Version 5.1.0 in Revit DLL
I'm attempting to use the MaterialDesignThemes WPF toolkit (version 5.1.0) in my Revit plugin, which is targeting .NET Framework 4.8. Despite installing the package via NuGet, I'm encountering an error saying the assembly can't be found, even though it’s included in the project.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve this?
Solution to solve the above issue.
